# Which values do "PANS-OPS" and "Standard" labels represent in the minimum table seperately? (minimums, circle-to-land values, aircraft categories...)

Tags: terminology, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, procedure-design

What is the difference between these two labels and which values do they represent in the minimum table exactly? ("PANS-OPS" and "Standard") What are the values that Standard and PANS-OPS labels represent separately? (Minimums, visibility, categories). Apart from the fact that they represent different documents and sources, the important thing to me is: Which label provides a reference to which values in the table? Because when I look at the explanations, it is said that it is determined according to EASA AIR OPS for "Standard" and ICAO rules for PANS-OPS. Minimum values, visibility values, circle-to-land values, speed values, and aircraft categories... I want to know by which reference source they were all determined.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for a published value to come from a particular source, yet also comply with another criteria?  (i.e. EASA comes up with the numbers, and ICAO approves of them...)

Comment: Actually, the indirect question here was why there are two labels. Having "Standard" and "PANS-OPS" makes it difficult and confusing for me to understand what they are referencing. But in conclusion, according to what you said, EASA determines the values and ICAO approves these values according to its own standards. Jeppesen also publishes it as a chart. I hope I am correct because I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: That seems to be what the published explanation says.